# Mobile Optomized Websites - Databases

Tags: html, database, json, drupal, mobile-safari

I want to create mobile applications for property and jobs directories. I can create basic application frameworks using BT (therefore my programming skills are very limited) but my main issue is trying to figure out the best way to incorporate the search function and directory databases in the apps. The companies I plan to work with already have these search functions and databases incorporated in their website. I would like the solution to be as simple and require as little maintenance as possible.

Therefore I think the best way around this would to be have the apps link to a mobile optimised version of the websites. My question is, what is the simplest and most low cost way to do this?

Is there any software program or application that can be used to convert these websites to mobile optimised versions or will these be big builds with a lot of custom coding involved?

I would like a solution that would work with the website backend and pull data, therefore anytime a listing is added, the mobile version would automatically update..

Comment: Might want to explain what BT is, I personally think "BitTorrent" when I see it.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a WebView is what you are looking for - you can display web components inside your application.
There is a nice tutorial here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

Answer (score 0):

Why not ask your companies DBA or webmaster to output JSON endoded query results.  then you can use your mobile code to read the json data (plenty of Stackoverflow examples).